# Python - Multiplying number in a list multiplies by the location (0,1,2,3, etc) instead of the value (2,4,6,8, etc)

Tags: python, for-loop, math

Here is my code so far:

```
numberList = []

n = int(input("Enter the list size: "))

for i in range(0, n):
        print("Enter number:")
        item = int(input())
        numberList.append(item)
m = int(input("Enter the number to multiply items in your list by:"))

for int in range(0, n):
        print(i,"*",m,"is",i * m)
```

This is for a class I am taking. We are supposed to have a user specify a list length, enter number for the list, enter a number to multiply the numbers in the list by, then print out the multiplication. So far everything is working as planned except the final print is multiplying by the location in the list, not the value. For example, the first item on the list is 2 and it's multiplying it by 5. Instead of 2 * 5 = 10, I get 0 * 5 = 0.

**How do I get python to multiply the value of the list rather than the place?**

Comment: For your second loop, instead of looping over the range, loop over the individual elements in the list like so `for item in numberList:` In that case, `item` will be the element you want to multiply. Also, you should avoid naming variables after Python builtins such as `int`.

Comment: @JamesMchugh That worked, thank you! Still getting the hang of all this. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: It is discouraged to use built-ins like `int` as variable names (in your second for-loop).

You're almost there. The only mistake is that in your second for-loop you iterate over 0 to n when instead you want to iterate over `numberList`, like so:

```
for i in numberList:
    print(i,"*",m,"is",i * m)
```